# Reply to Teams message using Microsoft Graph and Python

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I can broadcast to a channel in Teams using this following code, however is does not use the reply to id. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

```
def send_teams_message(team_id, channel_id, message, bearer_token, reply_to_id):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer_token}"
    }
    body = {
        "body": {
            "content": message
        },
        "replyToId": reply_to_id
    }
    response = requests.post(
        f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages",
        headers=headers,
        json=body
    )

    if response.status_code == 201:
        print("Message sent successfully.")
    else:
        print("Failed to send message:", response.status_code, response.json())
```

Comment: According to this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post-replies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http, you are not using the right url